Input on methodology for analysing publicly available medical datasets
I'm being asked to analyse a publicly available medical dataset of adverse drug reactions.
My data quality is quite sparse to begin with, so I've been trying my best to extract something meaningful from it. My research question is "which SSRIs are most associated with which ADRs"
I've stratified by sex to reduce confounding, turned a column of ADRs into dummy variables and used the following logistics regression model:
Type of ADR ~ Age + Type of SSRI
Keeping in mind that ADRs follow a MedDRA hierarchy which goes from most general 27 terms (such as Psych or Nerv) down to increasingly specific terms.  Most general 27 then 337 then 1737. I know a lot of models and a lot of multiple testing effects.


Even with 27 types of ADR (the least in your hierarchy), you would need a ton of data to estimate the logistic regression you posit. And I'm not even sure it would answer your question.
I'd start with a chi-square table of 27 rows and one column for each SSRI (the NIR lists 8 different ones) . This will likely have a lot of 0's (again, unless you have a lot of data) but there are exact methods. You may, however, have to lump some SSRIs together and that would have to be based on substantive knowledge.

Thank you for your response. Can I ask what you mean by exact methods?

There are a few different ones; the most common is probably Fisher's exact test,.  There are also tests based on permutations.
